# Storybook react-i18n missing key even after init and debug showing keys exist

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I am on a react project (Storybook)

Running i18n with `debug: true` shows all the keys inside translation

[image]

But I only see missing Keys on debug & on screen

I even have a Callback to ensure JSON was loaded, and even there the key is missing

```
i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    debug: true,
    returnNull: false,
    compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
    detection: {
      order: ['querystring', 'navigator', 'htmlTag'],
      lookupQuerystring: 'lang',
      lookupLocalStorage: 'lang',
      lookupCookie: 'lang',
    },
    keySeparator: false,
    fallbackLng: Fallback.i18nextFallback,
    appendNamespaceToMissingKey: true,
    parseMissingKeyHandler: (key) => `Resx:${key}`,
    defaultNS: 'Common',
    ns: ['Common'],
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    },
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          'Common': {
            'OK': 'OK'
          }
        },
      }
    }
  })?.then((t) => {
    alert(t('Common:OK'));
  });
```

Since debug is showing it correctly, why are my keys still missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, even though ALL their docs have `translation` as the first item inside `en`, `translation` is actually not required...

doing

```
resources: {
      en: {
        'Common': {
          'OK': 'OK'
        },
      }
    }
```

worked like a charm